# There is a way to put a legend into a graphics?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

There is a way to put a legend into a graphics? For example, given the `Graphics`

```
Graphics[{{Black, 
   Line[{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {-3, 4}}]}, {PointSize[0.015], {Red, 
    Point[{1, 1}]}, {Green, Point[{2, 3}]}, {Blue, Point[{-3, 4}]}}}, 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

I was able to put it in a `Legended`

```
 Legended[Graphics[{{Black, 
        Line[{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {-3, 4}}]}, {PointSize[0.015], {Red, 
         Point[{1, 1}]}, {Green, Point[{2, 3}]}, {Blue, Point[{-3, 4}]}}},
       Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}], 
     PointLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"A", "B", "C"}]]
```

but unfortunately, I was not able to do the contrary. So is it possible to do it? Could someone help me, please?

Comment: perhaps it's [Inset](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) what you're looking for

Comment: Unfortuantely it seems does not work. Ineed I just tried to put Graphics[{{Black, 
   Line[{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {-3, 4}}]}, {PointSize[0.015], {Red, 
    Point[{1, 1}]}, {Green, Point[{2, 3}]}, {Blue, Point[{-3, 4}]}}}, 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 Inset[PointLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"A", "B", "C"}]]] but it does not work.

Comment: Legends are used for plots. Are these legends going to be used as display items only? You can use a plot with any legend you want as `p1`  and then `Inset` that plot in your Graphics.

Comment: @Syed I have to create a graphics with a legend and so export it into an image png.

Comment: @Syed The following could be a possible solution: however If I indate as potion Right in place of {2,4} the result is stranger.

Comment: @Syed Graphics[{{Black, 
   Line[{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {-3, 4}}]}, {PointSize[0.015], {Red, 
    Point[{1, 1}]}, {Green, Point[{2, 3}]}, {Blue, Point[{-3, 4}]}}}, 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[PointLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"A", "B", "C"}], {2, 4}]]

Comment: @Syed So what do you think about?

Comment: It's good. You can try more variations and write your own answer to share your solutions.

Comment: Anyway I would know why is not possible to use the commands Right, Below, Left and Above to put the legend in the Graphics...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Graphics[{Black, Line[{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {-3, 4}}], PointSize[0.015], 
  Red, Point[{1, 1}], 
  Green, Point[{2, 3}], 
  Blue, Point[{-3, 4}], 
  Inset[PointLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"A", "B", "C"}], Scaled[{1.1, .5}]]},
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Recommend using [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)

```
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {-3, 4}};

ListPlot[List /@ data,
 Prolog -> {Gray, Line[data]},
 AxesLabel ->
  (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {"x", "y"}),
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue},
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed[{"A", "B", "C"}, {0.3, 0.4}]]
```

[image]